# scraping infinite scrolling website using phantomjs webdriverwait raises timeout exception unexpectedly

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I am trying to scrape a webpage that uses infinite scrolling to load new products with selenium and phantomjs. I know the total number of products on each page already and they load 21 at a time when the page is scrolled. My approach is as below

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get(response.url)

scrolls_needed = (int(response.xpath("//div[@class='count-text']/span/text()")[0].extract()) / self.PRODUCTS_PER_PAGE) + 1
for i in xrange(scrolls_needed):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda x:    len(x.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[contains(@id, 'divPictureAndPrices')]")) == self.PRODUCTS_PER_PAGE * (i+1))
```

I simply wait until the count of loaded items matching my xpath is equal to i * PRODUCTS_PER_PAGE. This approach works for all iterations except the last. At last iteration the equality condition inside until() call never matches and this causes a TimeoutException.

I would appreciate it if anybody explains how could I handle this error

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, simply changing the expected condition to:

```
lambda x: len(x.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[contains(@id, 'divPictureAndPrices')]")) >= self.PRODUCTS_PER_PAGE * (i+1)
```

should do the trick.

Comment: that was not correct actually but you gave me the idea to solve the problem. At each scroll down the page loads 21 new items but it does not mean that it has to load 21 items at the last scroll. I added a new condition  on which I am checking if that xpath expression is equal to total_nums_of_items. Thank you for your help